# Excel - how to add spaces in CELL("filename")

Tags: excel

How do I add spaces or "" in between `=CELL("filename")` in Excel.

e.g. I'm trying to create this:

```
C:\Users\Documents\Administration\Cleaning.xlsx
```

I have seen this in a formula ages ago, & now I need it & I've searched & searched & can't find this formula anywhere.

This is just to make it easier to read - as the file path is really long.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332).

```
=CELL("filename")
C:\Users\Documents\Administration\Cleaning.xlsx
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"), "\", " \ ")
C: \ Users \ Documents \ Administration \ Cleaning.xlsx
```

This answer above gets the job done. However, it technically is different from what you requested, which was for `C:\ Users` instead of `C:\Users`. If that's important to you:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"), "\", " \ "), ": \", ":\")
C:\ Users \ Documents \ Administration \ Cleaning.xlsx
```

Comment: Thank you so much Liyan Chang - your fast response is very much appreciated.  Kind regards, Roslyn